# Automation in django: Celery

Tags: django, python-2.7, automation, celery, django-celery

Django noob, please bear with me

How does to parse the rss/atom feed of an external site(any news site) and create a comments section for each post? Or simply on reddit where user submits the links; here the links are to be updated from a single/multiple websites and add a comment section.

Its easy to do with syndication framework, if site is in same db. But I couldn't find the exact solution and process to make it work for external sites. I have created the user model and comments model.I got stuck at automating the process of adding links.

Using django==1.8, python==2.7  Thanks a lot

EDIT: How to do it in celery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need, at minimum, a user model, comment model, article model, and most likely, a site model to store your RSS URLs and metadata about that site.

You will then need to create a function to parse the RSS from your URLs, and populate your article table. You will need to call this function on a periodic basis, either via Cron, or something like Celery.

The case of user-submitted articles is similar, although rather than a site model, you would need something like a category or channel model.

The rest is all forms and views.

The syndication framework does not parse RSS, it generates RSS from an existing model, so that's useless in your case, unless you intend to publish an RSS feed of your articles, linking to the comments pages (Reddit does this).

Comment: so, how to do it in celery?